# Testing endianess at compile-time: is this constexpr function correct according to the standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

After some search for a way to check endianess at compile-time I've come up with the following solution:

```
static const int a{1};

constexpr bool is_big_endian()
{
    return *((char*)&(a)) == 1;
}
```

GCC accepts this code only in some contexts where constexpr is required:

```
int b[is_big_endian() ? 12 : 25]; //works
std::array<int, testendian() ? 12 : 25> c;  //fails
```

For the second case, GCC says `error: accessing value of ‘a’ through a ‘char’ glvalue in a constant expression`. I couldn't find anything in the standard that forbids such thing. Maybe someone could clarify in which case GCC is correct?

Comment: Try compiling the first one with warnings on (hint: it's a VLA).

Comment: Well, C++11 doesn't have variable length arrays as far as I remember. Though, then it's a different bug, since I get no warnings with -Wall. BTW, I use GCC-4.7

Comment: I somehow doubt this is possible, on a fundamental level: Endianness is a property of the *implementation*, but compile-time magic happens purely as the result of applying the rules of the *language*. In particular, taking the address-of an object doesn't seem to be a compile-time concept.

Comment: Yes, now I've found where's the problem: the char* cast is a reinterpret_cast and this is explicitly forbidden.

Comment: @grumm143: `g++-4.7 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic a.cpp`. GCC sucks because it happily accepts VLAs (they're implemented for C99) unless you turn on really manly warnings (and I think it should be an *error*. I usually go for `-Werror` as well)

Comment: @Kerrek: you can take the address of some things at compile-time. I don't know details about what can and can't, but I guess that objects with internal linkage are fair game.

Comment: @grumm143: Damn, I didn't see your comment while writing my answer. :(

Comment: The default standard for gcc is gnu++, not c++, which is why it accepts some more permissive constructs than the strict standard.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Even something trivial like 'a' is defined by the implementation, and not by the language, and is surely a constant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what I get from Clang 3.1 ToT:

> error: constexpr function never produces a constant expression

`§5.19 [expr.const]`

> p1 Certain contexts require expressions that satisfy additional requirements as detailed in this sub-clause; other contexts have different semantics depending on whether or not an expression satisfies these requirements. **Expressions that satisfy these requirements are called *constant expressions*.**
>
> p2 A *conditional-expression* is a *core constant expression* unless it involves one of the following as a potentially evaluated subexpression:
>
> - [...]
> - a `reinterpret_cast` (5.2.10);

So, `(char*)&(a)` evaluates to a `reinterpret_cast`, as such the function is never a valid `constexpr` function.

Comment: @Matthew: Where did I look what up? The quote? It's from the C++11 standard.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into [Boost.Detail.Endian](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/detail/endian.hpp)

It is a mapping of several architectures to their endianness (through the macros BOOST_BIG_ENDIAN, BOOST_LITTLE_ENDIAN, and BOOST_PDP_ENDIAN). As far as I know, there is no actual way to determine the endianness at compile time, other than a list like this.

For an example implementation that uses Boost.Detail.Endian, you can see the library I'm hoping to get reviewed for submission to Boost: https://bitbucket.org/davidstone/endian/ (the relevant file is `byte_order.hpp`, but `unsigned.hpp` is necessary as well if you want to just use my implementation).

Answer (score 0):

If N3620 - Network Byte Order Conversion is implemented, you'll be able to use the constexpr `ntoh` to check for endianness, but remember there are rare architectures like middle-endian and you'll never be able to support all of them.